# Catch and pass hangout url to my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-plus, google-hangouts

I have a button to start a google hangout, everything works great, now I need to get the url using the

```
gapi.hangout.getHangoutUrl();
```

but I since this is a JS on my server, I know is possible to pass this to my app. But I don't know how (AJAX or anything else). I need this, because other user could join to this hangout.

Any suggestion with code would be appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your hangout script....

1. Include jQuery - it's useful for X-browser support.

   ```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Get the Hangout URL:

   ```
   var hoUrl = gapi.hangout.getHangoutUrl();
   ```
3. Get/Post the hangout URL to your server:

   ```
   var uri = encodeURI(server + '?hoUrl=' + hoUrl);
   $.ajax(uri,
     {
       async: true,
       beforeSend: function(request) {
         // Any beforesend code goes here, e.g. adding headers.
       },
       data: data,
       error: function(jqhr, status, error){
         // Error handling goes here.
       },
       type: verb,
       success: callback
     });
   ```
4. Handle the AJAX GET request and do your magic with the hoUrl parameter.

To clarify further:

A URL is formed before the AJAX get request to include a GET parameter, hoUrl, that has the hangout URL in it. Your server just needs to use whatever CGI/parameter parser to retrieve the 'hoUrl' parameter and then do whatever backend magic you want to do with it. Hope that helps to clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really new on webdevelopment, what is server, '?hoUrl' and paramString, haikuPlus, is an example of your model app right?

Comment: Whoops, lots of the wrong copy/pasted code in there. Cleaned it up for you. hoUrl is just a made up parameter to pass to your backend. e.g. if you search Google for cats, it passes a search parameter from a form. Please ignore the haikuPlus references, they are unrelated to this post and are just from a demo app.

Comment: I have this same problem and have a question. The above code is in `app.xml` in the Hangout App? Or is it somewhere in the main app? I included code similar to above in my `app.xml`, but it's not getting called. Also, some logs aren't logging. With the code in `app.xml` it doesn't seem to be communicating with my main app.

Comment: The above JavaScript is redirected using the Hangouts Hoster app - http://hostbot2000.appspot.com/ - or using the iframer tool - https://hangoutiframer.appspot.com/static/help.html - to protect against scenarios where CORS could cause issues.